# Can proc argument be variable

Tags: tcl

I just tried the following in tclsh:

```
proc pp {$ag} { puts hi}
pp  whatever
```

To my surprise, this works fine! I had expected a syntax error because the proc argument is a variable. But it seems tcl takes it fine.

Then I experimented:

```
proc pp {$ag} { puts "hi $ag"}
pp  whatever
```

and

```
proc pp {$ag} { puts "hi ${$ag}"}
pp  whatever
```

I got error, `can't read "ag": no such variable`.

This makes me wondering, can proc argument be variable? If not, why not error out in the first script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case works because you never use the parameter to `pp`.

When you invoke the `proc` command, the text of the invocation is evaluated just like in any other command invocation. In all the above cases, the third argument (which will become the argument list of the `pp` command) is is wrapped in braces, which means it won't be evaluated as a variable but as a string of three characters: "$ag" (i.e. the dollar sign is just a regular character here). This is *not* an error, and does work, just not the way you seem to expect it to.

It's a bit tricky to get the value of the parameter `$ag`, though. This works:

```
proc pp {$ag} {puts "hi [set {$ag}]"}
```

The dollar notation is actually just syntactic sugar for the unary `set` command. Sometimes the dollar notation won't work, and you need to fall back to an explicit `set`.

This does work too, though:

```
proc pp {$ag} {puts "hi ${$ag}"}
```

So, in your invocations, the third argument to `proc` isn't really a variable evaluation, it just looks like one. You can of course use an actual variable evaluation in the invocation of `proc`:

```
set foo {bar baz}
proc qux $foo {puts $bar ; puts $baz}
qux abc def
# => abc
# => def
```

What the Tcl interpreter really sees here is:

```
proc qux {bar baz} {puts $bar ; puts $baz}
```

Or you can go really crazy:

```
set foa {proc qux}
set fob {bar}
lappend fob baz
set foc {puts $bar}
set fod "puts \$baz"
{*}$foa $fob [join [list $foc $fod] { ; }]
```

Which amounts to the same thing as the previous invocation of `proc`. (If you don't believe me, try `list {*}$foa $fob [join [list $foc $fod] { ; }]`)

This example just looks (and is) weird, but many times it's actually useful to construct new commands within your program, and in those cases it's really nice that the text used in the invocation of proc, like with any other command, is simply text that the evaluation rules of Tcl can be applied to. You can use any kinds of string or list operations on it and join up pieces of text from various sources, even user input (if you can trust it).

Documentation: [Tcl evaluation rules including $ and {*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: The last example can be useful for "macros" if runtime matters, e.g. when calculating the MD5 hash.